# Div disappearing on resize

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a simple markup in which I am looking to stack two columns when below medium screen size.  I am using bootstrap to achieve this, however only one of the columns stacks and the other disappears.  The div that disappears is #purple-div

Any ideas?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div id="staff" class="row py-5">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="purple-div">
                <div id="staff-img"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>Staff</h4>
            <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum congue leo
                eget malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus
                convallis quis ac lectus.</p>
    
            <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget
                consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Sed porttitor lectus nibh.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the CSS (including any media queries) for `#purple-div` and `#staff-img`?

Comment: Please post your css

Answer (score 0):

Below medium size is (xs-sm), so you must change `col-md-6` to `col-6`

Comment: if you are not describe class for any sizes, its automatically choose `12` columns